# after calling proccess function - thread crashes

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, stack, calling-convention

```
static DWORD DamagePlayerAddress = 0;

__declspec(naked)
int __stdcall CallDamagePlayer
(
    int weaponID,
    uintptr_t* entityParamsPtr,
    int damage
)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, [esp + 4]  // weaponID
        mov ebx, [esp + 8]  // entityParamsPtr
        push[esp + 12]      // damage                   
        call DamagePlayerAddress
        ret 12
    }
}


DamagePlayerAddress = (moduleBase + 0x29c20);
```

This is the defined process function, that I want to call. (Inject the lib and call it). I reversed it with IDA, and decide to set __stdcall calling convention, cause of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4O9E.png) (its not cdecl). The function is cleaning up the stack itself, there is no any arguments  passed into ECX in [call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdPoO.png) of this function (so its not fastcall). And I debuged this stuff, there is no this pointer into ECX too (also its not thiscall).

Well, it seems that the calling convention is fine, but it still crashes after it runs the function (the function does some job, returns value, and then it crashes in some places of my code).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WkZi.png) is the IDA x32 disassemble.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUXdj.png) is the crash screenshot (into some func(in my code)).
Here is the exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0295A7CF in ac_client.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x776D1CFC.
```

Comment: Which instruction does it crash at when you single-step it with a debugger?   How does `call DamagePlayerAddress` assemble?  You probably need `call dword ptr [DamagePlayerAddress]` since there's a pointer or integer at that symbol address, not machine code.  Also, does the function it points to really take an arg in EBX?  That's normally call-preserved, but you destroy it. If it rets from there, what is ESP afterward?  Does the code at `DamagePlayerAddress` end with a `ret 4`, to balance the push you're doing?  If not, your `ret 12` runs with ESP not pointing at your original return address.

Comment: @PeterCordes
1. Added crash screenshot.
2. call dword ptr [DamagePlayerAddress]
3. I just saw that  IDA gives ebx register to the second argument (attached the screenshot with ida disassemble)
4. Dont understand what do you mean.
5 Yes, it ends with ret 4, attached the screenshot with assembly of this func.

Comment: You probably used a wrong return address and jumped to some data that's not actually machine code.  The instruction you crashed on, `add [eax], al`, has machine code `00 00`.  It's hard to imagine a real program where it's useful to add the low byte of a pointer to the pointed-to value.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that your `CallDamagePlayer` function destroys EBX is causing problems later on after you return, if you make it that far.  `__stdcall` functions (and any standard x86 calling convention) should return with EBX having the same value it had on entry.  The obvious thing would be to push ebx at the start, pop ebx right before ret.  (And adjust your ESP offsets to access your own args.  Or store EBX over top of `[esp + 4]` after loading it; callees own their stack args)

Comment: I dont understand too much in registers and assembly, but I think I know what problem it is. When I am debugging it - after function returns it goes forward through the code, but EBX register still has the address that were needed in the function DamagePlayerAddress. And then the code doing some stuff and crashes after it trying to "call ebx", but ebx is wrong. What can I do for fixing it? Or what did I done wrong?

Comment: I was just editing my previous comment with a suggestion to save/restore EBX in your function.  Yeah, if you get to bad code after a `call ebx`, that's pretty good evidence that this calling-convention violation is what's actually causing the problem.

Comment: saying "calling-convention violation" you mean __stdcall is wrong?

Comment: I mean that `__stdcall` tells the compiler it can assume that calling your function won't modify EBX.  Your actual hand-written asm violates that part of `__stdcall`, resulting in undefined behaviour.  There's nothing you can put there which will tell the compiler to expect what your function actually does, so you have to change your asm to follow one of the existing calling conventions the compiler knows about, so you can call it from C or C++ code.  (e.g. by saving/restoring EBX).